# Error The method RemoteWebDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined for the type MyDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am doing an example of automation in selenium with java in ecplipse, when I run the program, I get this error The method RemoteWebDriver (URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined for the type MyDriver

```
driver = RemoteWebDriver(new 
URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

complete code

```
package automation;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.net.URL;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class MyDriver {

private WebDriver driver;

public MyDriver(String browser) {
    switch (browser) {
    case "remoteFirefox":
    try
    {
         driver = RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    case "firefox":
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;

    case "Chrome":
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
        defautl:
            break;
        }

}

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.driver;
}
```

}

Comment: You should have got basic Java JRE jars with the creation of the Java project. For the other imports you should add the selenium server jar to your build path.

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Selenium selenium-java-3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to create new RemoteDriver, please add new and it should work

```
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
```